# Raspberry Pi 3 with Samsung charger

Tags: pi-3, power-supply

So I found a Samsung charger with no quick charge just a normal one.
But it outputs 5.3 V and 2 A. I've read at other forums that it shouldn't pass 5.25 V. So I wonder if it still safe to use it to my Raspberry Pi 3 B. If not recommend me what I should look for.

Comment: [Raspberry Pi Power Limitations](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/51615/raspberry-pi-power-limitations)

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi! Please take the [tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [helpcenter](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to see how things work here. I think that the linked duplicate sufficiently answers the question. If you feel that your issue is not addressed there feel free to edit your question and call for a re-open.

Answer (score 3):

The tolerance range for the supply voltage on the Raspberry Pi is 5V±5%, that means min 4.75V and max 5.25V. But ±10% should still be safe for electronic devices, so 5.3V will probably work, even though it is not perfect.

I have even read someone used a power supply with 5.7V, which still seemed to work fine. What I have read as well is that the Pi has a protection circuit which will cut off the power if it exceeds 6V.

So yours is probably fine and will not cause any damage.